# Sending Bulk Email To Members of Application

Tags: html-email, bulk, php

I've been reading up on sending mass email to a user-base, and I'm not feeling comfortable using the PHP `mail` function. It tends to be too simple, spammy and unreliable.

But that leads me to my question... for a custom application, what should I be using to send email to potentially hundreds of people? ...or is `mail` okay to use?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: mail() is just a conduit to sendmail, so it's really up to you what you put in it, using SPF, DKIM, etc. but it also means you have to do unblocking yourself in most cases. on a shared hosting I would go with SES though :)

Comment: What do you mean I can to do unblocking myself? And could you share the links to these abbreviations? :)

Comment: Since you asked, I've turned my comment into an answer and added some details :)

Answer (score 4):

I would use a third-party service. There are several of them. They ensure the emails are sent from white-listed IP's and have spent a LOT of money on legal prep for terms, privacy policy, etc to ensure the ISP's play nicely with the incoming mail.

If you're only sending mail to potentially *hundreds* of people, and not *hundreds of thousands* of people, PHP's `sendmail` will handle the load fine. You should be worrying more about the newsletter content and the opt-out easiness than the capability of PHP to send your email. For small campaigns to hundreds of people, check out [MyEmma.com](http://www.myemma.com) as an example of a small-list solution.

Comment: Can MyEmma be utilized remotely? In other words ... from my application, can I just sent MyEmma an object of all of the email addresses (and content) I want to send the email to? How exactly will MyEmma help me?

Comment: Yes most of those services, including MyEmma, offer an API. Here is MyEmma's: http://myemma.com/api-docs

Answer (score 3):

What you're probably looking for is an API to offload your email calls to and let a service handle the delivery for you. Sending a large number of email messages from PHP can be tricky as if it's not done quickly enough you run the risk of time-outs, and tracking which have been sent is always troublesome if you want to re-try a big batch.

Not surprisingly there are several companies which offer an email API service to make this sort of thing significantly easier than doing it yourself:

- [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) ([PHP example](http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/smtp-api/php-example/))
- [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) ([PHP package](http://packagist.org/packages/mandrill/mandrill)) from [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com)
- [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/) ([PHP libraries](http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-libs.html#php-5))
- [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com/) ([PHP example](http://help.postageapp.com/kb/quick-start-guides/php))
- [MailGun](http://mailgun.com/) ([PHP sample](https://github.com/aysark/mailgun.php))

While I'm a developer for [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com/), but I encourage you to try out many of these to see what works best for you.

In most cases you need to re-write a small portion of your application to work with the particular API or library used to access the API, and once that's done you can send a very large number of messages with one quick call. The delivery of those messages becomes the responsibility of your provider.

Comment: From what I can tell after spending a significant time using the Mandrill API is that Mandrill won't send bulk email ... it's only used for transactional, one-off emails. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The truth is that the less money you're willing to spend on email sending, the more things you have to do yourself, such as:

- White listing your sender IP address (especially if you're on shared hosting this can be a PITA, because the other users can mess things up for you).
- Setting up [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/) to add trust for mail hosts (Hotmail, GMail, etc.)
- Checking bounce emails
- Handling ISP complaints

This is also amongst the things that third party providers charge you for; if you don't wish to bother with any of the above, feel free to use providers such as Mailchimp, Bluehornet, etc. Make sure they provide what you need before you whip your wallet, some might have surprising hidden costs (such as charging you extra for API usage, use of transactional emails, life-cycle emails, etc.)

If you don't mind doing a few of the above (like checking bounce / complaint emails and making some simple DNS changes) you could sign up for [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/); it has a proper API and their email charges are the lowest I've seen so far and recently they have introduced DKIM (signed emails) support. You can also configure your sendmail (assuming dedicated hosting) to talk directly to SES, so it's easy to hook up any `mail()` based solution and run it.

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks for everyone that has helped me with this thus far.

The answer I was looking for is http://mandrillapp.com/

This is the service behind MailChimp and it rules in every way!